# Model was constructed with shape (None, 48, 48, 1) for input KerasTensor but was called on an input with incompatible shape (None,)

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

## update the data (image) and ages lists, respectively

```
            img_data.append(gray_image)
            split_var = file.split('_')
            ages.append(split_var[0])
            targets.append(age_group(int(split_var[0])))
        X = files
        y = targets
        x,y = shuffle(files,y,random_state = 3)
        
        X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, stratify=y, random_state=42)
        
       model.add(Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', input_shape=(48, 48, 1)))    # 3rd dim = 1 for grayscale images.
        model.add(AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
        
# Three Conv2D layers with filters increasing by a factor of 2 for every successive Conv2D layer.
        model.add(Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu'))
        model.add(AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
        
        model.add(Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=3, activation='relu'))
        model.add(AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
        
        model.add(Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=3, activation='relu'))
        model.add(AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
```

## A GlobalAveragePooling2D layer before going into Dense layers below.

## GlobalAveragePooling2D layer gives no. of outputs equal to no. of filters

```
in last Conv2D layer above (256).
        model.add(GlobalAveragePooling2D())
```

## One Dense layer with 132 nodes so as to taper down the no. of nodes from

```
no. of outputs of GlobalAveragePooling2D layer above towards no. of nodes in output layer below (7).
        model.add(Dense(132, activation='relu'))
```

## Output layer with 7 nodes (equal to the no. of classes).

```
model.add(Dense(7, activation='softmax'))
```

## Compiling the above created CNN architecture.

```
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

X_train=np.array(X_train)
y_train=np.array(y_train)

from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, EarlyStopping, ReduceLROnPlateau
early_stopping = EarlyStopping(
    monitor='val_accuracy',
    min_delta=0.00005,
    patience=11,
    verbose=1,
    restore_best_weights=True,
)

lr_scheduler = ReduceLROnPlateau(
    monitor='val_accuracy',
    factor=0.5,
    patience=7,
    min_lr=1e-7,
    verbose=1,
)

callbacks = [
    early_stopping,
    lr_scheduler,
]
h=model.fit(x=X_train, 
          y= y_train, validation_split=0.1, batch_size=32, 
          epochs=100, shuffle=True, verbose=2, callbacks=callbacks 
         )
```

Comment: Formatting should be changed

Comment: how please.. can you help me